# LyX cannot recognize my MacTex 2015

Tags: lyx, mactex, mac

My LyX system 2.1.3 cannot find my MacTex installation. When I choose Tools -> Tex Information, it appears completely blank.

So far I've done the following:

1. Completely removed MacTex  2015 and reinstalled it.
2. Reinstalled LyX.
3. Opened LyX through the terminal and reconfigured it.

I am running OS X El Capitan.

Thank you for any help you might provide!

Comment: You are using pre-release software, which likely makes this question off-topic. However, you might want to look at http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.macosx/47074 and following messages.

Comment: Thank you! I have it working through terminal, which is fine for now.

Answer (score 6):

Path handling has changed due to the new security framework in El Capitan. To fix it, go to the Paths item of Lyx → Preferences. Change the contents of the PATH prefix box from /usr/texbin to /Library/TeX/texbin. Then go to Tools → reconfigure and reset LyX.

Answer (score 2):

El Capitan has made some changes related to access to the /usr folder. The /usr folder is now read only even to the admin account. So the tex applications like MacTex are not able to create a symlink /usr/texbin to texbin folder. If one (not your case though since you reinstalled, just mentioning for the sake of generality) already had an installation of MacTex/Tex in previous OSx versions then the OSx update to El Capitan will remove the /usr/texbin symlink. Now either you can (re)install latest MacTex or follow the instructions below to symlink the existing Tex installation manually (as @DrMickeyLauer) mentioned in his answer:-

```
cd /Library/TeX
sudo ln -s Distributions/Programs/texbin texbin
echo "/Library/TeX/texbin" >~/Desktop/TeX
sudo cp ~/Desktop/TeX /etc/paths.d/TeX
```

Then run the following command to make the path available for current session :-

```
eval $(/usr/libexec/path_helper -s)
```

Confirm that the path is available :-

```
echo $PATH
```

If you want to rehash the files now, run :-

```
sudo texhash
```

Now open Lyx and ensure that the PATH variable in the Lyx -> Preferences reflects the new path to texbin

Then run Tools -> Reconfigure and restart Lyx.