# from Yosemite to El Capitan on Mac

Tags: lyx, mactex, mac

Today I updated my operating system from Yosemite to El Capitan on Mac. Lyx was not compiling the pdf anymore, so I used this system: https://tug.org/mactex/UpdatingForElCapitan.pdf

Although the issue per se is solved and Lyx says it compiled the pdf, it doesn't appear on the screen.

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Welcome! Have you tried opening the PDF?

Comment: Where is the pdf saved? I checked the library folder and is not in there and it does not appear automatically as before

Comment: I don't know. Isn't it in your working directory? Where do you find it if you want to email it to somebody?

Comment: We've seen a few reports of problems with El Capitan. See here for a possible workaround (and note the warning): https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg101934.html

Comment: @cfr Usually, the pdf was generated and opened without any further action before I updated the system

Comment: See also [LyX cannot recognize my MacTex 2015](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/254562)

Comment: I have not tried it but have you tried this: (http://osxdaily.com/2015/10/05/disable-rootless-system-integrity-protection-mac-os-x/) This disables the rootless feature and lets OS X again write into /usr /sbin and /System (default is not allow writes even with sudo) This disables it.